# Converting String to int in Java and getting a NumberFormatException, can't figure out why

Tags: java, string, integer, parseint, numberformatexception

ipString is a String representation of an IP address with spaces instead of dots.

```
String[] ipArray = ipString.split(" ");
String ip = "";
for (String part : ipArray){
    if (part != null){
        ip += part;
    }
}
ip = ip.trim();
int ipInt = Integer.parseInt(ip); // Exception is thrown here.
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "`6622015176`".
Could someone explain why this exception is being thrown?

Comment: Yep just tried it, it works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is primitive data type and it's range is : `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

`6,622,015,176` is out of int range.

Comment: Oh my god thanks so much I have been raging like a lunatic over this stupid problem, thanks for the fast reply too :)

Comment: You are welcome. You may need to consider using long or something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String ipString="662 20 15 176";
        String[] ipArray = ipString.split(" ");
        String ip = "";
        for (String part : ipArray){
            if (part != null){
                ip += part;
            }
        }
        ip = ip.trim();        
        Long ipInt = Long.parseLong(ip);
        System.out.println(""+ipInt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

6,622,015,176 This number is out of range of int.You should use long instead of int which will provide you a large range.